# React Native Firebase Dynamic Link pass data

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-native-ios, firebase-dynamic-links

[firebase dynamic links](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DZIrS.png)

I have successfully created an url prefix (giftittest.page.link) to which I have added a dynamic link (giftittest.page.link/list).

I followed the procedure to add an associated domain to xcode.
[xcode associated domains](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpCA6.png)

From safari I insert in the url 'giftittest.page.ling/list', it offers me to open my app, I press ok, the app opens correctly and I can intercept the dynamic link with the function

```
dynamicLinks().onLink(dynamicLinks => {
  console.log({dynamicLinks})
})
```

and

```
dynamicLinks().getInitialLink(getInitialLink => {
  console.log({getInitialLink})
})
```

how can I pass parameters to my app in query string?